# Android: Media Player Warning (1,44)

Tags: android, warnings, media-player

I am developing a soundboard application. In that, I use MediaPlayer to play sounds. I observe this warning in logcat which makes me worried.

```
WARN/MediaPlayer(340): info/warning (1, 44)
```

Everytime I play a file, am getting this warning in logcat. Do anyone know what this is about and how to solve it. I googled about this warning, but couldnt find any solution. Any help here is apppreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the log line in MediaPlayer's native layer:

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#C-hc3_GZ7SA/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp&l=571

If your sounds are playing ok I wouldn't worry too much about it. What format are they?

Comment: Do you know how to fix this warning?

Comment: No, am not familiar enough with Android's native layer. I expect it's some weird encoding artefact. Try opening them in something like Audacity and exporting them as MP3 (i.e. re-encoding them).

Comment: @Reuben,  i am playing an rtsp url via media player, the video and audio works fine in all devices except in Samsung devices with v2.2, in Samsugn v2.2 only the video plays without audio. i  am getting MediaPlayer info/warning (1,44), any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, Google murdered their Code Search product a year or two back (thanks Larry). I'm unaware of anything half as good as that was, but grepcode is alright for Java source.